# Polymer core-ajax cross domain issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, polymer

I am trying to do a cross domain call using Polymer and the [core-ajax](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-ajax) component. I keep getting back  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. My code for the component is below

```
    <core-ajax id="ajax"
        auto
        url="http://api.meetup.com/2/event_comments/?key=MyKey&event_id=191593992&callback=?"
        on-core-response="{{commentsLoaded}}"
        method='GET'
        contentType='text/javascript'
        handleAs="json">
    </core-ajax>
```

If I use jQuery and the following snippet, it works

```
$.getJSON('http://api.meetup.com/2/event_comments/?key=MyKeyc&event_id=191593992&callback=?')
```

So I guess my question is what voodoo magic is jQuery using that Polymer is not and how do I get around it? I have checked the console and everything looks identical (headers, params etc).

Comment: It would be useful to see which headers are sent (especially if the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is sent, and what its value is...)

Comment: jQuery is using `jsonp`. It looks like polymer has a jsonp example [here](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer-jsonp/demo.html) but I don't know enough about polymer to know if that will help you.

Comment: Awesome! I thought the ajax component would have jsonp integrated into it. Maybe I was missing an option or something. Anyhow thanks for pointing me to the jsonp component itself. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the aptly named Jason P points out in the comments above, you can use polymer-jsonp here.

```
<polymer-jsonp 
    auto 
    url="http://api.meetup.com/2/event_comments/?key=MyKeyc&event_id=191593992&callback=" 
    on-polymer-response="{{commentsLoaded}}">
</polymer-jsonp>
```

Answer (score 1):

On this note, polymer-jsonp has been deprecated.

The alternative is **core-shared-lib** which is described here:
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-shared-lib.html

And here is Github resource https://github.com/Polymer/core-shared-lib.

**core-shared-lib** supports sharing a JSONP-based JavaScript library.

Answer (score 0):

I know it been a while, but I just had the same trouble recently, and found Iron-ajax will perform an options request before it does the actual request, so I solved it by add a filter to response the options request. Following is my code in Golang if anyone interested in the details.

```
origin := c.Request.Header.Get("origin")
method := c.Request.Method

if strings.ToUpper(method) == "OPTIONS" {
    if origin == "" || strings.HasSuffix(origin, "domainname.com") {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")
        c.AbortWithStatus(204)
    } else {
        c.AbortWithStatus(400)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is deprecated, core-shared-lib substitutes the polymer-jsonp

Comment: Please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to improve its readability.  The current grammar makes it really hard to understand.