# How to make an JsonP request using ajax-core + Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm starting WebComponents and trying to use it with Polymer and ajax-core to ajax request.
I need to make a request to an API, but i don't know how to handle the CORS problem.

My code looks like.

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<polymer-element name="test-form">
<template>

<textarea></textarea>
<button on-click="{{buttonClick}}">Load</button>

<core-ajax id="ajaxSubmit" url="SomeExternalAPI" method="get" response="{{response}}"> 

</core-ajax>
</template>

<script>
Polymer("contact-form",{
    buttonClick:function(){
        this.$.ajaxSubmit.go();
    },
    responseChanged:function(oldValue){
        console.log(this.response);
    }
});
</script>

</polymer-element>
```

But this way of i'm getting the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. If you can have control over your backend you can enable `CORS`
2. Or you can use [polymer-jsonp](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-jsonp) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943956/polymer-core-ajax-cross-domain-issue) for example)

Comment: Thank you so much for reply, the example link is not working :(

Comment: Ok, i figured out how polymer-jsonp works. thank you.